# How can I find out the value of an Id from a Tapped view cell event

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have code to call an event when a ViewCell is tapped. In the event handler I need to know the Id value from the cell that called the event. can someone help suggest how I can get this value.

Also I would like to pass this value to the categoriesPage that is being opened. How can I do this?

```
public class CategoryGroupWordCountVM
{
    bool isToggled;
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsToggled { get; set; }
    public int TotalWordCount { get; set; }
}
List<CategoryGroupWordCountVM> categoryGroups;

foreach (var category in categoryGroups) {
    var cell = new CategoryGroupTextCell { BindingContext = category };
    cell.Tapped += openCategoriesPage;
    section.Add(cell);
}

async void openCategoriesPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctg = (CategoryGroupTextCell)sender;
    var Id = ??
    await Navigation.PushAsync(categoriesPage);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `BindingContext`

For example: (assuming CategoryPageVM is viewmodel-type for the page you are navigating to on tapped event).

```
async void openCategoriesPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctg = (CategoryGroupTextCell)sender;

    // get id from binding-context 
    var id = (ctg.BindingContext as CategoryGroupWordCountVM)?.Id;

    // construct or get viewmodel for the page you are navigating to
    var newPageVM = new CategoryPageVM { CategoryId = id };

    // assign viewmodel to page 
    var categoriesPage = new CategoryPage { BindingContext = newPageVM };
    await Navigation.PushAsync(categoriesPage);
}
```

Also, [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/#Passing_Data_when_Navigating) offers more details regarding passing data during navigation.